# How to select particular item in @Html.ListBoxFor using MVC 4?

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

How to select true particular item of `@Html.ListBoxFor()` control.
I know for selecting true all items in the `@Html.ListBoxFor()` control-
Hide   Copy Code

```
$("#List").find("option").attr("selected", true);
```

Please suggest how to select particular item in @Html.ListBoxFor control using JQUERY.

Comment: Unclear what your asking. Which options do you want to select. If you have options with values 1 to 10, then to select the 2nd and 4th ones it would be `$('#List').val([2, 4]);`

Answer (score 0):

pass it the selected values or use the other overeload and pass it the selectList which it's particular items has been marked as selected